# How to optimize this query as the in array seems to slow things down significantly

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am looking to find out the best way to optimize a query like this:

```
SELECT
  a.ID,
  a.ECPCodeID,
  a.RegDate,
  a.BusName,
  a.City,
  a.AccountNum,
  b.ID         as RepCodeID,
  b.RepCode
FROM ECPs_Registration a,
  Reps_Codes b
WHERE (SUBSTR(a.PostalCode,1,5)IN(SELECT
                    SUBSTR(Zip,1,5)
                  FROM Reps_Zip
                  WHERE RepCodeID = b.ID)
       AND a.AccountNum NOT IN(SELECT
                 ShipTo
                   FROM Reps_ShipTo))
     OR a.AccountNum IN(SELECT
              ShipTo
            FROM Reps_ShipTo
            WHERE RepCodeID = b.ID)
ORDER BY b.RepCode,a.BusName,a.City
```

I know there are more factors involved such as indexes and such, I just am asking about the query part of it for now.  Mainly, since I have to go through the Reps_ShipTo and Reps_Zip tables for tons of records.  I thought about changing something like:

```
a.AccountNum NOT IN (SELECT ShipTo FROM Reps_ShipTo)
INTO
(SELECT count(*) FROM Reps_ShipTo WHERE a.AccountNum = ShipTo) = 0
```

Not sure if that is proper or if there is a better way.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

EDIT:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ECPs_Codes` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ECPCode` char(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ECPCode` (`ECPCode`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ECPs_Registration` (
  `RegDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ECPCodeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `BusName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Address2` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Province` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `PostalCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `AccountNum` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ECPCodeID` (`ECPCodeID`),
  KEY `PostalCode` (`PostalCode`),
  KEY `AccountNum` (`AccountNum`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Reps_Codes` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `RepCode` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `AllAccess` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `RepCode` (`RepCode`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Reps_ShipTo` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RepCodeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ShipTo` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `RepID` (`RepCodeID`),
  KEY `ShipTo` (`ShipTo`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Reps_Zip` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RepCodeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `RepCodeID` (`RepCodeID`),
  KEY `Zip` (`Zip`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: instead of cartisian use join and add indexes

Comment: Can you show an example?  I have indexes on the relevant fields, just need help with the query.

Comment: Please post schema and sample data of your table than i will be able to help. Need complete information of relations

Comment: I added the schema.  Will put some sample data together if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that massively hurt performance on your query.

1. You are joining two tables by combining multiple conditions, each needing subqueries
2. You're doing a join on two tables using SUBSTR(Zip,1,5)=SUBSTR(postalcode,1,5)

The logic behind your query seems to be something like:

> For every `ECPs_Registration` find the matching record in `Rep_Codes`
>   using the following rules:
>
> - If there is a matching record in `Reps_ShipTo`, to for that registration, use that table to look it up (primary match)
> - If there isn't a matching record in `Reps_ShipTo`, seek through `Reps_Zip` for a matching RepCode by Zipcode-match (secondary)

Now if the above fully describes your situation, you should probably start off by redesigning your database.

The `Reps_ShipTo` table creates a 0:N relationship between `ECPs_Registration` and `Rep_Codes`. Such relations don't need an extra table - they can simply be stored as nullable foreign keys - in your case a `RepCodeId` in `ECPs_Registration` would do the trick, and would remove the entire Reps_ShipTo table from the database.

You should probably also create (yes, redundant) extra columns that only store the first 5 letters of the zip codes in both `ECPs_Registration` and `Reps_Zip`. This will allow simple equality matches instead of the SUBSTR-functions. Or, you might decide to do this match only once for every record, and store the result in above `RepCodeId`, which *totally eliminates* the dual join.

The following query assumes you for some reason don't want to or can't change your database:

```
SELECT 
  a.ID,  a.ECPCodeID,  a.RegDate,  a.BusName,  a.City,  a.AccountNum,
  CASE (b1.ID IS NOT NULL, b1.ID, b2.ID) as RepCodeID,
  CASE (b1.ID IS NOT NULL, b1.RepCode, b2.RepCode) as MyRepCode
FROM ECPs_Registration a
    LEFT JOIN Reps_ShipTo  ON (Reps_ShipTo.Shipto=a.AccountNum)
    LEFT JOIN Rep_Codes b1 ON (b1.ID=Reps_ShipTo.RepCodeId)
    LEFT JOIN Reps_Zip     ON (SUBSTR(Zip,1,5)=SUBSTR(a.postalcode,1,5))
    LEFT JOIN Rep_Codes b2 ON (b2.ID=Reps_Zip.RepCodeID)
ORDER BY MyRepCode,a.BusName,a.City
```

Without your database schema and sample data, I have no way to test if above query actually works and has the same result as your original.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  a.ID,
  a.ECPCodeID,
  a.RegDate,
  a.BusName,
  a.City,
  a.AccountNum,
  b.ID         as RepCodeID,
  b.RepCode
FROM ECPs_Registration a,   Reps_Codes b
INNER JOIN Reps_Zip as r on SUBSTR(a.PostalCode,1,5) = SUBSTR(r.Zip,1,5)
LEFT JOIN Reps_ShipTo as rs on a.AccountNum = rs.ShipTo
LEFT JOIN ShipTo as s on a.AccountNum = s.ShipTo
WHERE (s.id is null or rs.id is null) 
ORDER BY b.RepCode,a.BusName,a.City
```

Comment: I get You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Reps_ShipTo as rs on a.AccountNum = rs.ShipTo LEFT JOIN FROM ShipTo as s on' at line 12

Comment: dude, pls chk the query for urself.. I wrote it mistakenly as "left join from" pls remove the from and try.. I will also modify my answer accodingly.

Comment: Sorry I've been looking at queries for hours.  I fixed up a bunch of things with the query, but still extremely slow.  I think I may need to store the information for each to avoid this. Thanks.